# Does Google pull ratings from Google My Business and show rating in SERPs or only with Schema.org?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, google-my-business

I manage a low volume website, but with good SERP position.  So far I have only a few reviews in Google My Business (GMB).

My primary question is, does Google use the reviews/stars from GMB in the SERPs or only if I supply Schema.org?

If I have to use Schema.org, do I need a user review process separate from GMB?  Everything I read says I shouldn't copy reviews from other sources and that they need to be unique to my site.

As a secondary but related question:  Per Google guidelines, we aren't supposed to have reviews on our home page, only leaf pages.  This implies that the reviews should be product reviews versus company reviews.  My site advertises a service, and it doesn't make sense to create product reviews at the leaf level.  So, pulling GMB reviews makes more sense IMO.

Answer (score 2):

If people rate you on your Google My Business page, the reviews definitely show up in the SERPs. See this example of a restaurant with its Google local business ratings on the right-hand panel when the business is searched:

[image: Knowledge Graph Example]

Now if you mean that you want star ratings directly on the search entry for your own website itself, that's not something that you can do as easily, and something that I indeed think Google is trying to discourage with the "no reviews on home page" guideline that you mentioned.

> If I have to use Schema.org, do I need a user review process separate from GMB? Everything I read says I shouldn't copy reviews from other sources and that they need to be unique to my site.

You don't have to use Schema.org review markup to get GMB reviews to show up in your SERPs - they will show up naturally on the knowledge graph card to the right.

It is true that you cannot copy reviews into your own schema markup from other sources on the web:

> *[From Google:](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet)*
>
> - Ratings must be sourced directly from users.
> - Sites must collect ratings information directly from users and not from other sites.

In short, just make sure that you have claimed and optimized your Google My Business listing, then Google should show it in the SERPs.

Comment: Thanks @Maximillian.  The number of ratings don’t match with your example. That tells me the ratings are from different sources.

Comment: @Trebor What exactly do you mean by "the number of ratings don't match with your example"?

Comment: Compare the count of the number of reviews. The SERP shows almost 2,000 reviews while the GMB display shows substantially fewer at just under 800.

Comment: @Trebor The 1,994 reviews are Yelp reviews (they are shown on the Yelp SERP). The 791 reviews are Google My Business reviews, shown only on the knowledge panel. So it's totally true that the ratings are from different sources!

Comment: you are right.  I didn't see that.  Sorry. Still, I'd like to see a SERP star rating that matches GMB if Google indeed uses GMB ratings in the SERP list as opposed the side panel and a direct search of the company name.

Comment: @Trebor A side-panel star rating *is* a SERP star rating, technically speaking! Do you mean you'd like to see a rating on the result for your business' own website? If so, afaik there is no consistent way to achieve that without skirting guidelines. I've never seen GMB ratings in the search results list, only on the knowledge panel. I'm pretty sure they can't appear in the SERP list (unless maybe you get really weird and specific with your queries).

Comment: Yes @Maximillian, that is the question I'm asking.  If none of the star ratings I see in the list ing SERPs (Not the side knowledge panel) are coming from GMB, then that means that every one of them come from someone adding schema.org markup.  That seems counter to what Google is trying to accomplish given the potential of manipulation.  I'd like more than just anecdotal evidence though one way or the other.

Comment: @Trebor It is true that they all come from crawling on-site reviews ([not necessarily schema markup always though](https://searchengineland.com/10-facts-rich-results-seos-know-289078)). But Google only chooses to show rich snippets in search when they are from review sites. Google uses site reputation in their formula to prevent manipulation, and also crawls the page manually to make sure the reviews are there on-page. As I mentioned in my answer, review schema cannot be copied from other sites as it is against guidelines. So it is impossible to show your GMB rating on your site's result.

Comment: @Trebor The important difference here is that review sites like Yelp collect user reviews on a leaf page about an entity separate from the site itself, versus your site which does not collect reviews on the site, and if it did it would be about the same entity the site represents, which starts to get hairy with Google's guidelines.