# Is it ok to add an AggregateRating schema with Google Reviews according to Google guidelines?

Tags: seo, google, schema.org

[Google Technical Guidelines for Review Snippet](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/review-snippet#technical-guidelines) state:

> Don't aggregate reviews from other websites.

Should I understand here that they do not want third party content here ? Like the former Facebook reviews. Are Google reviews themselves ok? Or this is only intended to be used on websites that have their own review system.

Context: a local business website.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120328/does-google-pull-ratings-from-google-my-business-and-show-rating-in-serps-or-onl

Comment: @Trebor Definitely related. Thanks! But not a clear answer + the content referenced in the docs in the not in the docs anymore which adds to the confusion.

Comment: It still says `Don't aggregate reviews from other websites.`.  The docs also have a reference to why in this blog post.  https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful#updated

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, basically this page states that reviews are not taken into account if they are about the current site to avoid self serving. I don't find mention of `other websites` on this page though.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the article you originally linked to that says `Don't aggregate reviews from other websites`.  That article had a link to the blog post as to "self serving" aspect.